# " sudo su - " is switching the user but files are getting created with parent id

Tags: linux, permissions, su

We have one bash command with one user "useradm" which runs a command as

```
sudo su - platfrmapi; sh script.sh
sudo su - platfrmapi; cp script.sh script_2.sh
```

The user-switching is happening perfectly, but the logs which are created as part of "script.sh" are owned by "useradm" instead of "platfrmapi".

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your commands are chained together with a semicolon, meaning they are performed **independently**!  First, the `sudo` command runs and switches to the platfrmapi user; that process must eventually exit, which allows the second command to run, which is `sh script.sh`; that second command is still running as the original user, because the `sudo su -` command has *exited*.

What you seem to want is for the `sh script.sh` to run as the platfrmapi user, so do this:

```
sudo -u platfrmapi sh script.sh
```

... assuming the useradm user has the correct sudo permissions to execute `sh script.sh`.

It would be more direct to ensure that the script is executable (`chmod +x script.sh` and has the proper sh-bang line) and then execute it directly with:

```
sudo -u platfrmapi ./script.sh
```